# How to connect with a neo4j graph database using Cypher and procedures?

Tags: android, neo4j, cypher

I'm developing my first android app (a  social media kind-of App) and after some research found that a graph database (specifically Neo4j) could be the adecuate solution for data storage. I've been also been in touch with graph theory and graph algorithms lately and decided to give it a shot.

I've grown an interest on GDB due to how intuitive and easy is to understand and represent relationships between entities this kind of DB. I've also liked  Cypher Query Language ([Neo4j Query Language](https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher-query-language/)) intuitiveness for retrieving information from graphs. Thats the reason I would like to connect my app with a Neo4j database.

What I want to do is remotely storing my users database and retrieve user information for login. After some research I've found that Neo4j has different [language's drivers](https://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/) including one for Java. And since Java is Android official language **I would like to know if Neo4j java API will work on my Android project**.  Reading through Neo4j [API documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/) though, there's a statement that says that it has been [deprecated](https://screenshots.firefox.com/GOa2FFYpPojSeWqk/neo4j.com) and that I should use cypher and procedures instead,  but I've failed on finding documentation about this.  **What would be the way to connect my app with a neo4j GDB using Cypher and procedures?**.Where can I find some tutorials, documentation, examples to achieve

Please keep in mind that I'm still a beginner in Android development and GDB. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Forget REST. Look for using graphql (pros: only data you need, less network calls). There must be a lib for Android to consume gql, certainly from FB.

Look for the graphql plugin at https://github.com/neo4j-graphql/neo4j-graphql

However, be aware of security if you put your gdb on the web directly.

Will Lyon (Neo4j)'s article : https://www.oreilly.com/learning/building-a-simple-graphql-server-with-neo4j